# Click event cannot be fired on buttons created dynamically in VB.Net ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm creating a code in Page_PreRender function to dynamically creates some labels and buttons:

```
Dim btnExcludeDr As New Button()
btnExcludeDr.ID = "btnExcludeDr"
btnExcludeDr.Text = "Rate Driver"
form1.Controls.Add(btnExcludeDr)
AddHandler btnExcludeDr.Click, AddressOf Me.cmdExcludeDrv_Click
```

And the event which must be fired for each btnExcludeDr button is:

```
Protected Sub cmdExcludeDrv_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
   MsgBox("hello")
End Sub
```

But the event is not fired. Do you have any solution? thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to create your dynamic controls is in the `Page_Init` function that the page code-behind class provides.

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
    Dim btnExcludeDr As New Button()
    btnExcludeDr.ID = "btnExcludeDr"
    btnExcludeDr.Text = "Rate Driver"
    form1.Controls.Add(btnExcludeDr)
    AddHandler btnExcludeDr.Click, AddressOf Me.cmdExcludeDrv_Click
End Sub


Protected Sub cmdExcludeDrv_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MsgBox("hello")
End Sub
```

Comment: Page_Load or Page_Init ?? I saw you created it in Page_Load !

Comment: Method signature does not matter - the compiler only cares about `Me.PreInit`. I have changed the method signature label to reflect this.

Comment: I asked you because the code I have in my page contains both of these two methods (`Page_Init` and `Page_Load`) and they don't have `Handles Me.PreInit` !

Comment: You can use Page_*event* convention when you have `AutoEventWireup` decleration configured in aspx view. Please see this for more information https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w2tb12s.aspx